# Replace lowercase with uppercase in a filestream

Tags: c#

I´m trying to replace *lowercase* characters to *uppercase* in a text, using a `FileStream`. I´m using this code, but it seems that `WriteByte` won´t overwrite the character. Could you help me out with that? thanks!

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("./texto.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

for (int i = 1; i <= fs.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLower(Convert.ToChar(fs.ReadByte())))
    {
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);               
        fs.WriteByte((byte)char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(fs.ReadByte())));                        
    }
}
            
fs.Close();
```

Comment: One thing you should note is that you're calling `fs.ReadByte()` _twice_, so you're not overwriting the correct byte.

Comment: If performance is a concern at all you should instead read the file into a buffer, make the changes there, and then write that out again.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I forgot to mention that i´ve been asked to make changes on the same FileStream, i cannot create a new one...

Answer (score 0):

The procedure has two issues:

1. `fs.ReadByte()` is called twice (as already noted @C.Evenhuis)
2. doesn't take in accounts the text encoding; for example if the file was UTF-8-BOM the update file would have at start three "dirty" chars (three BOM byte converted)

From the design point of view, would be better isolate the "business" rule.
Based on these considerations I propose this refactoring:

```
var fileToModify = "TextToUpdate.txt";
var fileEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var readingStream = new FileStream(fileToModify, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var writingStream = new FileStream(fileToModify, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

var bw = new BinaryWriter(writingStream, fileEncoding);
        
foreach (var charToWrite in readingStream.ToUpperChars(fileEncoding))
{
   bw.Write(charToWrite);
}
        
readingStream.Close();
writingStream.Close();
```

Following the extension method `ToUpperChars` that isolates the business rule:

```
public static IEnumerable<Char> ToUpperChars(this Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    var br = new BinaryReader(stream, encoding);

    Boolean eof = false;
    Char charToReturn = Char.MinValue;

    while (!eof)
    {
        try
        {
            charToReturn = br.ReadChar();

            if (Char.IsLower(charToReturn))
            {
                charToReturn = Char.ToUpper(charToReturn);
            }

        }
        catch (System.IO.EndOfStreamException)
        {
            eof = true;
        }

        if (eof)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return charToReturn;
        }
    }
}
```